# Giving a Randomly Chosen Variable From a List a Certain String Value

Tags: python

So I'm currently making a tic tack toe game where you play against the computer, and I can't seem to figure this part out.  I want the computer to select a random variable from a list of positions that haven't been used yet, and make that variable's value O.  Here is what I have currently.

```
#positions is a list of variables that start off = ''

positions = [ul, uc, ur, cl, cc, cr, ll, lc, lr]

comchoice = randrange(0, len(positions))

while positions[comchoice] != '':
    comchoice = randrange(0, len(positions))
else:
    positions[comchoice] = 'O'
```

EDIT: This question is different than the one that it is said to be a duplicate of.  It is different because it is asking about changing the value of a variable in a list.  It's clear in my post that I understood the duplicate post's question with my code.

Comment: `ul, uc, ur, cl, cc, cr, ll, lc, lr` are not defined

Comment: Why do you pick a new change for comchoice in the while loop?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque they are all `= ''` see the comment in the code.

Comment: @DewaldAbrie the `while loop` is so that the computer doesn't pick a variable that is already used.  so if the user or the computer already placed an x or an o the computer will keep looking until it finds a blank variable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for me:

```
from random import randrange

positions = ['']*9

comchoice = randrange(0, len(positions))

while positions[comchoice] != '':
    comchoice = randrange(0, len(positions))
else:
    positions[comchoice] = 'O'

print(positions)
```

Producing:

```
['', '', '', 'O', '', '', '', '', '']
```

Comment: Okay I think that makes sense.  instead of trying to change the variables, make the list index the thing i'm inputting.  I'll play with it a bit and see if it works for me.  thanks